# Some friends on the Facebook website do not appear in the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was playing with the Graph API recently and I made the following simple call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`

For me, this returns 461 entries. On my profile page on the Facebook website, I have 465 friends. On the following page, I have 477 friends:

`https://www.facebook.com/me/friends`

I've discovered that 12 of my friends has deactivated their profiles, which would account for the difference between the 477 and the 465. However, that still does not explain the difference between the Graph API call and the number that appears on my profile.

This leads me to my questions:

1. Is there a way to retrieve a list of inactive friends via Facebook API?
2. What other reasons are there aside from user inactivity that a friend connection would not appear on the Graph API? Is there a user's privacy setting for such control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely normal behavior. There is an option in Facebook that let's you disable all apps. Reference: [Facebook: Disable all apps](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=211829542181913) If they have that turned on, your app to not be able to reach them.

As of finding inactive friends, the answer is NO, you can't not. They are not a part of the Facebook public platform and therefore you don't have access to them.